# PHP; Iterate through an assoc. array and add together all values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have an array that I need to 'merge' the values of, and then flatten the entire thing to not be associative. I have this working, but I was hoping to find a better way.

Here's, in essence, the array:

```
array (
    [label] => array(
        [0] => array(
            key => val
        )
        [1] => array(
            key => val
        )
    )
    [label2] => array(
        [0] => array(
            key => val
        )
    )
```

What I do with this is to add all values from [0] and [1] per assoc. array and return 1 array, where the output is something like:

```
array (
    [label] => array(
        [0] => array(
            key => SUM(val1+val2)
        )
    )
    [label2] => array(
        [0] => array(
            key => val
        )
    )
```

I do this by:

```
$i = array();

foreach ($array AS $key => $val) {
    $i[$key] = NULL;

    foreach ($val AS $r) foreach ($r AS $k => $v) {
        if (count($array[$key]) > 1) { // Add value.
            $i[$key][$k] += $v; 

        } else { // Leave alone.
            $i[$key][$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I flatten it into one big array by using:

```
$array = array();

$r = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
);

foreach ($r as $key => $val) 
    $array[$key] = $val;

return $array
```

I think this is ugly and could be done in a much more efficient way. I just can't figure it out, and SPL confuses me; but I want to learn.

Can someone help?

---

I think I figured it out:

```
    $data = array();
    $RII = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($it)
    );

    foreach($RII AS $key => $val) {
        $data[$RII->key()] += $RII->current();
    }

    $this->fullData = $data;
```

Did everything I needed to in less code. Does this look right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array();
$RII = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($it)
);

foreach($RII AS $key => $val) {
    $data[$RII->key()] += $RII->current();
}

$this->fullData = $data;
```

Replaces both functions above. It goes through the multidimensional array without question and allows me to do what I needed to do.